# remove the first duplicate line based on a matched field and keep the second matched line

Tags: unix, awk, duplicates, match

1. Input file has 3 fields. Each field separated by a **|** (PIPE).
2. First field is the key field and sorted. Each key in first field may occur once or twice.
3. If a same key exists twice in first field, then remove the line of
   first occurrence and do not remove the line of second occurrence.
4. If a key occurs only once then do not remove the line.
5. Input Data in the third field will be unique through out the file.

Tried the below command which keeps the first duplicate line and removes the rest of duplicate lines. Is there any option in awk command to remove the first matched duplicate line and keep the second matched line. Command other than awk is also okay. Input file size can be 50 GB size. I am testing now on 12 GB file.

```
awk -F'|' '!a[$1]++'
```

Input File Content:

```
1|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
2|xxx|{name: "abcfgs"}
3|xxx|{name: "egg"}
4|xxx|{name: "eggrgg"}
5|xxx|{name: "xsdsyzsgngn"}
5|xxx|{name: "gbgnfxyz"}
6|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
7|xxx|{name: "xynfnfnnnz"}
7|xxx|{name: "bvbv"}
8|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
9|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
....
```

Output expected after processing the input file:

```
1|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
2|xxx|{name: "abcfgs"}
3|xxx|{name: "egg"}
4|xxx|{name: "eggrgg"}
5|xxx|{name: "gbgnfxyz"}
6|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
7|xxx|{name: "bvbv"}
8|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
9|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
....
```

**EDIT**

Tried below solutions provided by  **@RavinderSingh13** & **@RomanPerekhrest** repectively.

For 12GB input file, below solution took 1 minute 20 seconds in first run and 1 minute 46 seconds in second run:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="|"
}
!a[$1]++{
  b[++count]=$1
}
{
  c[$1]=$0
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print c[b[i]]
  }
}
' Inputfile  > testawk.txt
```

For 12GB input file, below solution took 2 minutes 31 seconds in first run, 4 minutes 43 seconds in second run and 2 minutes in 3rd run:

```
awk -F'|' 'prev && $1 != prev{ print row }{ prev=$1; row=$0 }END{ print row }' Inputfile > testawk2.txt
```

Both the solutions are working as expected. I will use any one of the above after doing few more performance tests.

Comment: I didn't see any duplicated remove from the expected output. Please elaborate.

Comment: @JamesBrown it did. the key is `$1`

Comment: What about the 3rd, 4th, ... should they be removed like the 1st ? What about the case of NO duplicate, do you still need to see the first instance ?

Comment: In your example, is the prefix '5|xxx|' just mean line 5 of input file xxx ? or is it part of the input ?

Comment: Why does the expected output include the 'xyz' from line 1 - should it be removed because of the 'xyz' in line 6 ?

Comment: The file has a total of 3 fields separated by I (Pipe). First field is having some ids like 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. These numbers are the data and not the line numbers in the file. XYZ is  data in second field. If no duplicate in first field then the line should be retained. There is no possibility of more than 2 dupliates i.e a value in first field can occur only twice or once.

Comment: Is the input file sorted on the first field?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, it is sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1st solution:*** If you are not at all worried about order of your lines in output then do simply.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"} {a[$1]=$0} END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Adding 1 more solution with `awk` less arrays and `sort` in case you worried about order.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"} {a[$1]=$0} END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}' Input_file | sort -t'|' -k1
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Could you please try following. If you are worried about order of your output should be same as shown Input_file.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="|"
}
!a[$1]++{
  b[++count]=$1
}
{
  c[$1]=$0
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print c[b[i]]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
2|xxx|{name: "abcfgs"}
3|xxx|{name: "egg"}
4|xxx|{name: "eggrgg"}
5|xxx|{name: "gbgnfxyz"}
6|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
7|xxx|{name: "bvbv"}
8|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
9|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
```

Comment: keep in mind that OP said the file is 50G. the `c[]` stores the whole file, if I understood the codes right.

Comment: @Kent, yes true, lemme put 2 times Input_file reading concept too, but not sure if that will be faster than this or not.

Comment: @Kent, Hi sir, how about my 2nd solution? IMHO this should be faster than my previous one I believe, what you say sir.

Comment: it is not about faster or slower. I don't know what it would happen if OP's system has <50G free memory.

Answer (score 2):

Efficiently with **`awk`** expression:

```
awk -F'|' 'prev && $1 != prev{ print row }{ prev=$1; row=$0 }END{ print row }' file
```

The *"magic"* is based on capturing each current record (efficiently overwriting it without constant accumulation) and performing analysis on ***next*** row.

Sample output:

```
1|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
2|xxx|{name: "abcfgs"}
3|xxx|{name: "egg"}
4|xxx|{name: "eggrgg"}
5|xxx|{name: "gbgnfxyz"}
6|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
7|xxx|{name: "bvbv"}
8|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
9|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner will **only remove the first duplicate (the 2nd occurrence)** from your file.

```
awk 'a[$1]++ !=1' file
```

Let's see an example:

```
kent$  cat f
1
2
3
2 <- should be removed
4
3 <- should be removed
5
6
7
8
9
2 <- should be kept
3 <- should be kept
10

kent$  awk 'a[$1]++ !=1' f
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
2
3
10
```

Comment: For me, the first occurrence should be removed and the 2nd occurrence should be present.

Comment: @inzero so you only want to have duplicated data? E.g. `5` in my example, there is no dups, it should be kept or not? please make a better input/output example. I am completely confused.

Comment: @inzero if you have 10 lines with the same key, you want to have 2nd-10th lines in your output?

Comment: there will be only 1 or 2 lines with same key.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the file and stable unique sort:

```
cat <<EOF |
1|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
2|xxx|{name: "abcfgs"}
3|xxx|{name: "egg"}
4|xxx|{name: "eggrgg"}
5|xxx|{name: "xsdsyzsgngn"}
5|xxx|{name: "gbgnfxyz"}
6|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
7|xxx|{name: "xynfnfnnnz"}
7|xxx|{name: "bvbv"}
8|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
9|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
EOF
tac | sort -s -t'|' -k1,1 -u
```

would output:

```
1|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
2|xxx|{name: "abcfgs"}
3|xxx|{name: "egg"}
4|xxx|{name: "eggrgg"}
5|xxx|{name: "gbgnfxyz"}
6|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
7|xxx|{name: "bvbv"}
8|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
9|xxx|{name: "xyz"}
```

The `tac` is a GNU utility. Because your file is big, pass the filename to `tac` so it can read the file from the back and use `-T, --temporary-directory=DIR` option with `sort` to allow it to sort such big files (or not, if you have enough ram).